# How to print diagonals of a N X N box? Check my code?

Tags: c++, c, c++14

```
int main()
{
    int n, i, j;

    cin >> n;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i + j == n - 1)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            else
                cout << " ";
        }

        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is something like this (it should print diagonal of 5x5 if I enter no 5 )

```
  *     *
   *  *
    *
  *  *
*      *
```

Comment: Code should be indented to make it readable, the actual output should also be included, and there should be some text in the question that asks the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 for-loops to draw the pattern. A single loop will do.

Just keep track of the position of the two stars.

Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 6;
    int starApos = 0;
    int starBpos = n - 1;
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (starApos < starBpos)
        {
            printf("%*s", starApos, "");                // spaces before A
            printf("*");                                // A
            printf("%*s", starBpos - starApos - 1, ""); // spaces between A and B
            printf("*");                                // B
        }
        else if (starApos == starBpos)
        {
            printf("%*s", starApos, "");                // special case: only 1 *
            printf("*");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%*s", starBpos, "");
            printf("*");
            printf("%*s", starApos - starBpos -1, "");
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");

        ++starApos;    // Move positions
        --starBpos;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output n = 6:

```
*    *
 *  *
  **
  **
 *  *
*    *
```

Output n = 5:

```
*   *
 * *
  *
 * *
*   *
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the fist diagonal correctly, instead of `i + j == n - 1` put `i + j == n + 1`.
Finally, add `|| j == i` to make the other diagonal.

I also recommend you to delete the `i == 0` (`i` starts at 1 and only goes up so it will never be 0), add a better indendation to your code and replace the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` with `#include <iostream>` if you don't really need it.

Your program should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {

        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i + j == n + 1 || j == i)
                cout << "*";
            else
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a program fully in C, then the following code works. Make sure you look for the relationship between the row and column 'indexes' at each `*` in the X (i.e. pretend that the X you are forming is a 2D array).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int size = 0;

    // Ask user to enter size of x, then scan input 
    printf ("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    // Only an odd input can be accepted 
    if (size > 0 && size % 2 != 0) {

        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            
                if (row == col) {
                    //Print one diagonal 
                    printf("*");

                } else if (row + col == size - 1) {
                    //Print the other diagonal 
                    printf("*");

                } else {
                    //Print empty spaces 
                    printf(" ");
                }
            } 
            
            //Move to next row 
            printf ("\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```